# NGINX rewrite/location regex redirect /index.html$ -> /

Tags: regex, redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

I want to maintain one single URL for all pages and I'm using the `index index.html` directive to have a page at `/writing/index.html` be displayed when someone visits `/writing/`. However, with this index directive `/writing/index.html` is still a valid URL that nginx serves a page at.

I want `/writing/index.html` to 301 redirect to `/writing/`, and so forth for the root path (`/index.html` -> `/`) and all other URLS too (`/foo/bar/index.html` -> `/foo/bar/`).

I want to use a regular expression that only matches the /index.html ending such as: `^(.*/)index\.html$`

But if if I add

```
  rewrite "^(.*)/index\.html$" $1 last;
```

to my nginx conf I'm seeing `/writing/index.html` 301 redirect to `/writing/` which is good but I also see `/writing/` 301 redirect to `/writing/` in an infinite loop.

So my question is why does that above rewrite regex match `/writing/` when it does not end in `index.html`? Is it because of the internal index directive in the nginx conf?

I've seen other one off solutions on StackOverflow for redirecting a single path, but not a solution that does it in a clean/generic way like this.

Below is my current nginx.conf

```
server {
  listen         80;
  server_name example.com *.example.com;

  charset utf-8;

  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";

  gzip_vary on;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_comp_level 6;
  gzip_buffers 16 8k;
  gzip_http_version 1.1;
  gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

  rewrite "^(.*/)index\.html$" $1 permanent;

  location / {
    root /srv/www/example.com/;
    index index.html;
  }

  error_page 404 /404/;
}
```

Comment: Just a guess... could be that nginx is recursively matching it? which means that the /write/ URL is not matched by the regular expression but once it's re-written to /write/index.html it matches it and it loops.

Comment: @Fawix yeah, I think something like that is happening. There is some internal re-routing that is then getting caught by the `index` directive. Any idea on how to prevent that from happening though?

Answer (score 1):

So the solution to this problem was to have the rewrite inside a location that checks against the actual request's `$request_uri` which avoids internal re-routing with the `index` directive.

Pretty much use this instead:

```
if ($request_uri ~ "^(.*/)index\.html$") {
  rewrite "^(.*/)index\.html$" $1 permanent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe a location block with a return would be more efficient and easier to read:

```
location ~ ^(.*/)index\.html$ {
    return 301 $1;
}
```